# In SailsJS i want to get specific fields and display to html

Tags: sails.js, sails-mongo

This is my codes. i got result when i was using find() all fields but i want to use find with where condition that produce error. what should i change ??

```
index : function(req, res, next) {
   User.find({}).where({userlevel:{'=' : 'admin'}}).exec(function (err, usernames) {
        if (err) { 
            res.send(400);
        } else {

            res.view({
                usernames : usernames

            });
        }

    },
```

i want to get all admin usernames from mongoDB..

in html

```
<% _.each(usernames,function(err,user) { %>

            <%= user.usernames %>

        <% }) %>
```

Error :

```
usernames not defined..
```

pls help me..I am new to Sails

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
index : function(req, res) {
   User.find().where({userlevel: 'admin'}).exec(function (err, users) {
        if (err) { 
            res.send(400);
        } else {
            res.view({
                usernames: users
            });
        }

    }
```

Note that `users` is a list of users, not just usernames.

In your view:

```
<% _.each(usernames, function(user) { %>
    <%= user.username %>
<% }) %>
```

Comment: I updated the answer. Can you share the model code with us as well? The code in `api/models/User.js`.

Comment: attributes: {
   
   username: {
    type: 'string'
   
   },............
    userlevel: {
    type: 'string'
   
   },
   }

Comment: So it seems that it was a typo. In your view it should be `user.username` (like in my answer), not `user.usernames`.

Comment: hi..sorry ..attributes: { usernames: { type: 'string' },............ userlevel: { type: 'string' }, }  .this is correct

Comment: Could you change in the controller `res.view({usernames: users})` to `res.view({users: users})`? Because you are using `username` in both controller and view, so it's ambiguous. After you change this you should check if the error stays the same: `usernames not defined`